# why Python modules are available depending on the imports done?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

- I'm using Python 2.7.6.
- I'm using [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as an example of Python library ([source code, version 3.0.3](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/d98367d1df80f06e653cf2bafd5d4d92138fc861/?at=v3.0.3)).

If I do:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
```

I can use `BlockingScheduler` normally with:

```py
s = BlockingScheduler()
```

But I cannot achieve same goal doing:

```py
import apscheduler
s = apscheduler.schedulers.blocking.BlockingScheduler()
```

Because it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'schedulers'
```

But if I do:

```py
import apscheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
s = apscheduler.schedulers.blocking.BlockingScheduler()
```

It works perfectly.

- **Why is this behaviour happening?**
- **Why can I not obtain full submodules list using the short import?**